# Overloading function when passing lambda as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, sfinae

I'm trying to implement template function when return parameter is either void or T. I tried different variations of the code above using sfinae but still not sure if that is in general possible in case lamdba is function parameter.
The following code does not compile :

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
T Apply(const std::function<T()>& func)
{
    return func();
}

template <>
void Apply(const std::function<void()>& func)
{
    func();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i1 = Apply([]() { return 10; });
    bool b1 = Apply([]() { return true; });
    Apply([]() { return; });

    return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
error C2672: 'Apply': no matching overloaded function found
error C2784: 'T Apply(const std::function<T(void)> &)': could not deduce     template argument for 'const std::function<T(void)> &' from 'main::<lambda_536cc9cae26ef6d0d1fbeb7b66a2e26b>'
```

[wandbox live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dpZKMmrc6bMX0tdF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [template deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) needs a perfect-ish match for each of the function arguments in order to successfully deduce  the template parameters.

You'd need to templetize the function object itself:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class Function, class Return = std::result_of_t<Function()>>
Return Apply(Function func)
{
    return func();
}
```

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << Apply([]() { return 42; }) << "\n";
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/170452850bacbcfb)

Comment: Amazing! I have slightly updated with SFINAE :  [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JFJPOiisPPui8MJa)

Comment: Interesting if there is a way to make the following code compile : int i1 = Apply([](int i) { return i; });. In this case, I need explicitely 'int' to Function() when deducing Result ( = class Return = std::result_of_t<Function(int)>). But is there a more generic way to deduce lambda parameters ?

Comment: @drus the keyword you're looking for is (perfect) forwarding. And this can be achieved with C++17. Look around, test, and if you're stuck ask a new question about it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't do that because the implicit conversion (from lambda closure type to `std::function`) is not considered in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction); the code fails because `T` can't be deduced.

You can use the lambda closure type as the parameter type directly, and declare the return type as `auto` to be deduced automatically. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
auto Apply(T func)
{
    return func();
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i1QnFtO1j4cPuyTF)

Comment: Writting too mutch C++98 deter me from using `auto` when appropriate :/ +1

Comment: @YSC This is really powerful feature of C++11/C++14, we should use them as more as possible.

Comment: @YSC "when appropriate" sometimes it's not though ... and the code just gets confusing since you don't know what type things are.  Not my favorite C# import to the language I've got to admit!   (here though it seems to work!)

Comment: @songyuanyao If it wasn't clear, this is exactly my opinion.

Comment: "implicit conversion is not considered in template argument deduction" this is commonly said, but it's not quite true, I think this phrase is guilty of confusing people. Derived->base, CV, and array pointer conversions are all implicit and all can occur while calling a function template whose parameters are deduced.