# Injecting lambda as parameter to template method

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, sfinae

I'm trying to implement something similar to `boost::static_visitor`, have template function accepting lambda and supporting the following API:

```
int i1 = Apply([](int i) { return i; }); // doesn't compile
int i2 = Apply([]() { return 10; });     // ok
bool b1 = Apply([]() { return true; });  // ok
Apply([]() { return; });                 // ok
```

The question is continuation of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424942/overloading-function-when-passing-lambda-as-parameter).
The implementation

```
template <typename Function, typename Return = std::result_of_t<Function()>,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Return, void>::value>::type>
Return Apply(Function func)
{
    std::cout << "invoked via Return(*)(...)" << std::endl;
    return func();
}

template <typename Function, typename Return = std::result_of_t<Function()>, 
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Return, void>::value>::type>
void Apply(Function func)
{
    std::cout << "invoked via void(*)(...)" << std::endl;
    func();
}
```

works fine if lambda doesn't have parameters

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Function, typename Return = std::result_of_t<Function()>, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Return, void>::value>::type>
Return Apply(Function func)
{
    std::cout << "invoked via Return(*)(...)" << std::endl;
    return func();
}

template <typename Function, typename Return = std::result_of_t<Function()>, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Return, void>::value>::type>
void Apply(Function func)
{
    std::cout << "invoked via void(*)(...)" << std::endl;
    func();
}

int main()
{
    int i1 = Apply([]() { return 10; });
    bool b1 = Apply([]() { return true; });
    Apply([]() { return; });

    std::cout << i1 << " " << b1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But if lambda has parameters, `std::result_of_t< Function() >` needs parameters list to be passed to deduce result type of lambda (e.g. `std::result_of_t< Function(int) >`).

Comment: Just squinting my eye's I am thinking variadic templates. Please post a [MCVE] that compiles and runs in the no-parameter case.

Comment: Links in questions are verboten.

Comment: @JiveDadson: That's not true. However, your edit is correct - don't link to small code snippets; they belong inline.

Comment: Hey, @drus, how about giving a green check mark to an answer?

Comment: Jive, I'm afraid none of solutions do what I need. I stopped for now with lambda having no parameters.

Answer (score 5):

One size fits all. :-)

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) Apply(Function&& func, Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "invoked" << std::endl;
    return std::forward<Function>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
    int i1 = Apply([]() { return 10; });
    bool b1 = Apply([]( bool b)  { return !b; }, true);
    Apply([]() { return; });
    std::cout << i1 << " " << b1  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or, better yet, just use `std::invoke()`.

Comment: I believe you should make `Args... args` parameter pack universal references via `Args&& ... args` to prevent an extra copy when those parameters aren't temporaries

Comment: @Howard -- Done.  Did I do it right?  If not, please edit.

Comment: Almost. You should return `decltype(auto)`, because without it, you won't return a reference if `func` does. Also, some people prefer to forward `func` too, because call operators can also have ref qualifiers, but this is very rare, so you don't really need to. (Also: templates are implicitly `inline`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper class to get the return type of the lambda.

```
template<typename T>
struct ReturnVal {};

template<typename ReturnType, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct ReturnVal<ReturnType(Class::*)(Args...)> {
    using type = ReturnType;
};

template<typename ReturnType, typename Class, typename... Args>
struct ReturnVal<ReturnType(Class::*)(Args...) const> {
    using type = ReturnType;
};
```

Then you can use it by passing the `decltype` of the `lambda`s `operator()`.

```
template<typename Func>
void someTemplateFunction(Func func) {
    using Return = typename ReturnVal<decltype(&Func::operator())>::type;
}
```

With this approach you get the benefit of being able to pass in a function pointer to `ReturnVal` aswell. You can also use it to extract the parameter types.

Comment: This won't work with a generic lambda (or any manually defined functor with a template `operator()` or more than one `operator()`), but Jive's answer does.